# Ubuntu/Cordova/Android SDK: AVD Target not showing

Tags: 18.04, java, android-sdk, gradle

A Web Developer trying to create android app using Ubuntu 18.04 with Cordova (v.8.0.0) requirements show:

```
    Android Studio project detected
    Requirements check results for android:
    Java JDK: installed 
    Android SDK: installed true
    Android target: not installed 
    avdmanager: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml    /bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:213)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)... 5 more
    Gradle: installed /usr/lib/gradle/4.8.1/bin/gradle
```

I used Android Studio to create the AVDs:

```
emulator -list-avds
Nexus_5X_Nougat_7.0
Nexus_S_Marshmallow
```

I have tried:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin/avdmanager create avd --force --name testAVD --abi google_apis/x86_64 --package 'system-images;android-25;google_apis;x86_64'
```

But I get the same error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml    /bind/annotation/XmlSchema
```

I've tried different versions of Java/SDK and Gradle, Ionic and so on. **There is a step missing in every instructions and all debug do not clearly explain the step of Android target: not installed.**

Answer (score 1):

You can try by adding this environment variable

```
export JAVA_OPTS="--add-modules java.xml.bind"
```

Answer (score 0):

Define which API version you need.
For example, if you target android 10 you need API platform 29. In the following, replace 29 by the API version you need.

You need sdkmanager. Type :

sdkmanager --install "platforms;android-29"

In the project directory, open config.xml

add :
<platform name="android">
<preference name="android-targetSdKVersion" value="29" />
</platform>

Between the existing <widget> ... </widget> tags